# Downloading JSON data iOS 10

Tags: php, ios, json, nsurlsession

I am having trouble using `URLSession` to access JSON data generated by a PHP file.

I am both confused about the Swift 3 syntax and the completion handlers.

So far I have:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var data : NSMutableData = NSMutableData()

        let urlString: String = "http://seemeclothing.xyz/service.php"
        let urlObject: URL = URL(string: urlString)!
        let response = URLResponse
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let sessionObject: URLSession

        sessionObject.dataTask(with: urlObject) { (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) in
            print(data)
            print(URLResponse)
            print(Error)

        }
        sessionObject.resume()
    }
```

I want `sessionObject` to go to my server and print JSON data from PHP file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What issue are you having with the code you posted?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire). It abstracts away all the tedious stuff in `URLSession`. I switched to this a few days ago and am a happy camper since then.

For your problem:

```
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").responseJSON { response in
    print(response.request)  // original URL request
    print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
    print(response.data)     // server data
    print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

    if let JSON = response.result.value {
        print("JSON: \(JSON)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is Alamofire well supported? Does it work with https as well as http?